# Add calculated column from server side script in datatables

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatable in my php code.

my server server-side processing script here

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'val1', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'val2',  'dt' => 1 ),
);
```

here problem is that how i get another unbound column val3
which have value of val1+val2 .

**Example :**

```
val1 val2 val3
1    2    3
3    5    8
```

here val1 and val2 is database column and val3 is calculated column.

I am stuck right now that how to add val3 column from server-side script.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to write DB query from server side for getting 3rd column.
2. Client side keep 3 columns table code (html)

   ```
   <table class="table results" border="1">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>val1</th>
               <th>val2</th>
               <th>val3</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
   </table>
   ```
3. Client side define 3 columns (jquery datatable)

   ```
   results= $(".results").dataTable({
       aLengthMenu: [ [10, 25, 50, 100, 150, "-1"], [10, 25, 50, 100, 150, "All"] ],
       iDisplayLength: 10,
       searching: true,
       "aaSorting": [],
       "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
       "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

       "bProcessing": true,
       "serverSide": true,
       "bDestroy": true,
       "cache": false,
       "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo $serverside_php; ?>",

       "sDom": 'T<>lfrtip',
       "oTableTools": {
           "sRowSelect": "os",
           "aButtons": [ "select_all", "select_none" ]
       },

       "aoColumnDefs": [
           { "bSortable": false },
           { "data": "val1" },
           { "data": "val2" },
           { "data": "val3" },
       ],
   });
   ```
4. Feed the server side response data to client datatable + html

Comment: Seems like my link is broken, anyhow write a query which will give you 3 columns the way you want where last column would be sum of first two and feed the values to table.